# Single threaded OpenGL ES Android application

Tags: android

I'm trying to create single threaded OpenGL application for Android like in [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/16a2216b39513674#) example.

But when I added onTouchEvent, onKeyDown and onKeyUp methods in the activity class, application starts to work very slowly.

Also I tried to add sleep(20) into the onDraw method, but it didn't help.

Please, tell, how I should to organise my single threaded OpenGL app?

Comment: Please post some code to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

You will find that when you listen for a touch event you will start getting them very rapidly with multiple events per touch. Each of these events will stop any rendering and call your listener's code which will make your rendering appear slow.

You've reached a limitation of having a single threaded renderer here, and the next step would be to use another thread for the rendering.

For now, rather than sleeping inside your onDraw method, try sleeping in your event handler.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792185/why-are-touch-events-destroying-my-android-framerate) and the [linked post by Dianne Hackbourn](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/39eea4d7f6e6dfca?pli=1).